How to find the chart number in excel?
If I am generating a chart using VBA, I want to know how to find the chart number which I am generating or I want to know how can I assign a particular number to a chart while I am generating. I will attach my code below. Here I am trying to assign chart 12. Since I couldn't able to assign or know the chart number I am using Errorhandler..
Sub Macro2()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    ' Determine the last row and column in Sheet2
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lastCol As Long
    lastRow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lastCol = ws2.Cells(1, ws2.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    ' Contour
    Dim chartRange As String
    chartRange = "A1:" & Split(Cells(1, lastCol).Address, "$")(1) & lastRow
    ws2.Range(chartRange).Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(307, xlSurfaceTopView).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=ws2.Range(chartRange)

    ' Assign the chart name to "Chart 12"
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 12").Name = "Chart 12"

    ' Access the chart properties using the fixed chart name
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 12").ThreeD.RotationX = 90
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 12").ThreeD.DepthPercent = 2000 ' Set the Depth (% of base) to 100%
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MajorUnit = 20
    ActiveChart.Legend.Select
    ActiveChart.Legend.LegendEntries(9).Select
    With Selection.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    ActiveChart.Legend.LegendEntries(10).Select
    With Selection.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 12").ScaleHeight 2.5202019539, msoFalse, _
        msoScaleFromBottomRight
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 12").ScaleHeight 1.4428858489, msoFalse, _
        msoScaleFromTopLeft
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False

    ' Add chart title
    ActiveChart.HasTitle = True
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Efficiency Map"
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error"
    Resume Next

I tried to to assign the value and also used ChartObjects.Count to find the integer value.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shapes.addchart2#:~:text=Returns%20a%20Shape%20object%20that%20represents%20a%20chart%20and%20adds%20it%20to%20the%20specified%20collection. AddChart2 returns the added shape object, so use that to refer to the chart.

Hi Williams thanks again for your response. I am actually using AddChart2 in the 14th line itself, but the problem happening when I want to change the name, size of the chart, and also color. Therefore at 19th line code say "ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 12")" this number is making things complicated. I want to know how can I edit or get the number I create everytime

So use the returned shape and not trying to get the shape/chart by name. e.g Set MyChart = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2( ...

@Shrotter didn't understand your answer.

@ManishVarmaRaathimiddi you may have a look on this example, which shows you to use the returned shape. the object MyChart you could use in following code
